# Who is creating/maintaining the Unified components for PCB?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, schematics, altium, footprint

In Altium, I noticed that there are 'Unified components' - the repository that contains symbols/footprints that are already created. I am keen to know more about this repository. Who is maintaining it? Who created the symbols/footprints inside it? And why isn't it a global thing to have it done for all ICs and not a select few?

Answer (score 2):

Altium created the libraries them selves, but they no longer maintain it.
Altium offers a central component vault as part of their services ($).